# Order pagination with limit and offset

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pagination

If I have 3000 rows.

**Page 1**

```
Select * from clients order by id limit 1000 offset 0;
```

**Page 2**

```
Select * from clients order by id limit 1000 offset 1000;
```

**Page 3**

```
Select * from clients order by id limit 1000 offset 2000;
```

My question is about the internal processing of postgres.

I am using the order clause to avoid duplicate entries and the consistency of the pagination.

```
Page 1 1000 rows
Page 2 1000 rows+1000 rows
Page 3 1000 rows + 1000 rows + 1000 rows
....
```

Therefore, the higher the page number, higher the time it will take. This is correct and normal? Or there is another approach?

The offset and the order always need to know the previous results, right?

Comment: Remember the last id, and use `where id > 'last_seen_id' order by id limit 1000`. I've written answers with more detail before. Only works when your ordering key is stable though.

Comment: @CraigRinger ok, but if i have multiples ids with the same value? Possibly I will have duplicates (example, same row in two different pages). My problem is not a issue with 3 pages, but it is a big problem with 4000 pages or something.

Comment: Well, you'll have the same problem with your current approach. You might get different records in different orders each time, so you see some more than once and never see others. You must have a sort key that fully specifies an unambiguous sort order.

Comment: @CraigRinger How? In my approach, If the table is read only and immutable, the index position will be always the same, even if i have multiples ids with the same value. the last_seen_id will works only with unique keys, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on the scan and sort method chosen. Only a cursor will guarantee what you want in the absence of an unambiguous sorting key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table id OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1000;
```

On a performance level, it means we are asking DB engine to figure out where to start from all on its own, every time.
Which means it must be aware of every record before the queried offset, because they could be different between queries (deletes, etc).
So the higher offset number, the longer the overall query will take.

**Alternative Solution**

Instead, of keeping track of an offset in query script, consider keeping track of the last record’s primary key in the previous result set instead

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 999 LIMIT 1000;
```

This way DB’s engine will know exactly where to start, based on an efficient indexed key, and won’t have to consider any of the records prior to range. Which will all translate to speedy queries.

Comment: see https://developer.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/an-efficient-alternative-to-paging-with-sql-offsets/ for the full article where this answer was basically copy/pasted from.

Comment: @jkraemer and why is that a problem? It is the right answer to the question. Edit the answer to include a reference if you like.